# Cannot install ubuntu 20.04 sgx disabled by bios

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, debian

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 on asus vivobook x507ua but I am getting following error after choosing bootable usb driver
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVmis.jpg)

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
```

Comment: Did you verify your ISO prior to write to media? otherwise (*and more likely*) its the write to media that was faulty - why you're getting an invalid media detection error (ie. no medium container is found).  The offer to download it is offered given no valid ISO was detected on the media....

Comment: "sgx disabled by bios"  has nothing to do with this. The next line does. If you want that msg gone add `nosgx` to the boot params when you get to the grub prompt.

Comment: I downloaded the ISO from release.ubuntu.com and boot it using power ISO in USB, I dont know where things gone wrong, I will try again thanks for your help

Comment: In my experience the write of ISO to media fails the most, did you write it in a method verified for that release of ISO as not all ISOs can be written with the same software; these are *tested* and *proven* methods - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Thank you, I reboot the os with verified tools and it worked